# When is onCreateViewHolder called and why? RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Up to this point I thought that `onCreateViewHolder` in `RecyclerView.Adapter` was called when I was calling adapter's constructor with `adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, list)`, but I realised that it is actually called at the end of Activity's `onCreate` method after all the code is executed, is the reason for that have something to do with that the RecyclerView doesn't create unnecesary views, and creates only how many can fit on the device's screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called when `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` determines which and how many views will be visible within `RecyclerView`, and `RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool` does not contain enough `ViewHolder`s to re-use.

This usually happens during each layout phase and on (first) scroll.

Comment: Is there a way to control the initial count of view holders created? I see in my case it creates 2 on initial load and then on first scroll several more. So the first scroll is a bit laggy, at least in debug, because of that (checked with systrace). Happens rarely in release config, and it's barely noticeable.